# Export file from FTP with API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ftp

Does anyone know whether there is a way to connect with SFMC enhanced FTP with API, and export a certain file?

It seems like a simple solution, but I am not getting anywhere with the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the system you like to fetch files from, there is no need to do so via an API as the (S)FTP protocol is capable of doing so and almost any programming language supports this protocol or has packages/libraries that do so.

This might also be the reason why there is no (or at least no standard and documented) endpoint for interacting with files on the enhanced FTP.

**Some possibly helpful resources:**

- If you are using Node.js: [ssh2-sftp-client module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client)
- If you are using Python: [pysftp](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/)
- ...

Comment: Thanks Markus. The npm package was exactly what I was looking for.