# Retreive file present in ftp from cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, cloudpage, marketing-cloud-connect, ftp

I want to know if there is any script/function where I can retrieve a csv file present in FTP from a cloud page.

Firstly the file is already present in FTP location, so some users don't have access to FTP.

Is there any function that I can use in cloud page to retrieve the csv file present in FTP, when we click the cloud page URL it should be downloaded the csv file.

I don't want to use the AttachFile option.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately. SSJS and Ampscript are quite limited when it comes to utilising e.g. FTP protocol, and the Enhanced FTP folder is not able to expose its files over HTTP(S) (which would be required, if you were to download it via a Cloud Page).

Comment: thanks @Lukas, so the final conclusion is there is no way we can access file from cloud page, I came across this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292272/export-file-from-ftp-with-api but am it did not mention the points in details, can api be one of the approach?

Comment: @Joey the thread you are referring to does not mention any API, only the ability to use e.g. Python package to allow it to access the file via the FTP protocol. Something neither SSJS nor Ampscript are capable of.

Comment: thanks @Lukas for your response